# How do I filter with more than one letter in primefaces selectonemenu?

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using primefaces selectonemenu. As user request me to have the option to type more than one letter to have filtering, now it only works on one letter. is it possible?? I have extracted my code of the selectonemenu on the xhtml file. Hope it helps. Thanks for your help:

```
<p:selectOneMenu required="true" requiredMessage="#{esMessage['WARN.ESTTC3S5.COURSETYPE']}" id="ddCourseType" value="#{dtWebVoEsttc3s4.courseTypeId}" height="300" style="width:421px"
  onchange="subListUpdate();" effect="fade">

<p:ajax listener="#{dtSelectedCourseTitleVo.filterList(dtWebVoEsttc3s4.courseTypeId, dtCourseTitleVo)}" update="ddCourseTitle" />

<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{esLabel['lbl.esttc3s4.lblselectcoursetype']}" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />

<f:selectItems value="#{dtCourseTypeVo.courseTypeList}" var="courseType" 
    itemLabel="#{language.localeString eq 'zh'? courseType.courseTypeChi: courseType.courseType}" itemValue="#{courseType.courseTypeId}"/>

</p:selectOneMenu>

........................................................



<p:remoteCommand id="teacherNameListRemoteCommandId"    
  name="subListUpdate" action="updateCourseTitleListData3s4Form"    
  update="ddCourseTitle" />
```

Comment: Can´t you control filtering on java side? By the way, p:selectOneMenu has filterFunction attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the filter option from `selectOneMenu` component?

```
filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
```

Source: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

EDIT: Of course you can set the match mode to different options like `contains` or whatever you want

Comment: You can even define a filterMatchMode="custom" and a filterFunction attribute, it's a javascript function with 2 arguments (itemLabel and filterValue) to check the size of the filter